# Java: Finding total telephone cost for bill

Tags: java

This is an assignment where I have to put in a number of minutes and the code will calculate the cost. One of the instructions was that fractional minutes are not allowed. The code is working very well but this is only the problem I have:

I want that when I put in a number for example 1.5, it will say "Fractional Minutes are not allowed"

```
    double numberOfMinutes       = 0.00;
    double additionalMinutesCost = 0.60;
    double totalCost             = 0.00;
    double cost                  = 0.00;
    double extra                 = 0.00;
    double teleCost              = 2.50;

    //Display banner
    System.out.print("Welcome to Kenneth's Telephone Company\nBill Calculator\n\n");

    //Promt user for minutes
    System.out.print("Please enter the Amount of minutes: ");
    numberOfMinutes = keyboard.nextDouble();

    if (numberOfMinutes ==0) {

        System.out.print("Amount due: $0\n\n");
        System.out.print("Thank you for working with us\n");

    } else {

        //Check number of minutes
        if(numberOfMinutes >=1 && numberOfMinutes <=3) {

            System.out.println("Amount due: $2.50\n"); 
            System.out.print("Thank you for working with us\n");

        } else  {

            //Calculate additonal cost
            extra = numberOfMinutes -3;
            cost = additionalMinutesCost * extra;
            totalCost =  cost + teleCost;

            System.out.printf("Amount due: $%.2f\n\n", totalCost); 
            System.out.println("Thank you for working with us");
        }
    }
```

Can you guys help me with this?

Comment: You haven't even made an attempt!

Comment: I tried when I was at school but it didn't work so I deleted it so it would not mess up my work.

Comment: Have you considered using `%` (modulo) operator?

Comment: `(int) numberOfMinutes != numberOfMinutes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// check if input is not an int

if (numberOfMinutes != (int)numberOfMinutes){
   System.out.print("Fractional Minutes are not allowed\n\n");
}
```